# connect: multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable)

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to build my first node.js application, but, running using `node server.js` I get the following error message :

> connect: multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable)
>   directly connect: limit: Restrict request size at location of read

as shown by this screenshot:

[image]

snippet of code in which I'm using `connect`:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(connect.cookieParser())
    .use(connect.session({secret: 'app_1'}))
    .use(connect.bodyParser())
```

How to fix this, please?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`connect` is [deprecated](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#middleware) since `express.js` version 4. Try installing the middleware ([1](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser), [2](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser), [3](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session)) separately like this:

```
$ npm install cookie-parser --save
$ npm install body-parser --save
$ npm install cookie-session --save
```

And in your code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cookieSession({secret: 'app_1'}));
```

Comment: it's not possible to define it as a dependency in the `package.json` file ?

Comment: @Luciekulza, that is what the npm --save-dev does. You can always do it manually too, if you wish

Comment: okay, but what's the difference between `devDependencies` and `dependencies`, please ?

Comment: Sorry. Not concentrating. I amended my answer to `--save`. `--save-dev` is `devDependencies`, `--save` is `dependencies`

Comment: np, thank you, but, the cookieSession doesn't need to take any args ?

Comment: would you please write the new code? because i'm getting some difficulties to do that.

Comment: I now expanded it to include the args for cookieSession and also the `var app` declaration

Answer (score 3):

replace

.use(connect.bodyParser())

into

.use(express.urlencoded());
.use(express.json());

source
https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1793

edit: full code

```
var connect = require('connect'),
express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(connect.cookieParser()) // i use express.cookieParser, but connect.cookieParser should also work 
  .use(express.urlencoded());
  .use(express.json());
```

Comment: Would you please write the full code of your suggestion?