# cannot make .get calls in node + express localhost

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, localhost

I was working fine and suddenly when i restart the server it returns this error:

```
connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable) npm mo
dule instead node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\bodyParser
.js:56:20
connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read node_modules
\express\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:86:15
Listening on port 3000...
```

The server is up, but the .get ajax calls are not longer working, obviously due this. Here's my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();
    app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/gomerias.json', function(req, res) {
    res.send();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

How can i resolve the deprecated issue here?. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using express 4. So you are getting this error. You can install package individually `body-parser`,  `cookie-parser`, `cookie-session`

Install package by:

```
npm install package-name
```

I also got a problem when suddenly change express version. Then this Reference [connect: multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy, formidable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012708/connect-multipart-use-parser-multiparty-busboy-formidable) helped me.

Your updated code should be

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session')

var app = express();
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(bodyParser());
    app.use(cookieSession({secret: 'app_1'}));

app.get('/gomerias.json', function(req, res) {
    res.send();
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

Comment: Hi there. I've tried what you suggested but i'm receiving the same error. I also tried with -g but it's the same.

Comment: thanks for that, however i receive this error now: "Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-parser'"  Is the module name correct?. Thanks

Comment: I've installed each package individually, however the .get calls are still not working. Check the call:                                                                                             $.get( "gomerias.json", function( data ) {
          getCoordinates(data);
 });                                                                                                        Any idea?. Regards.

Comment: I've found out the uri for the json file was wrong, and to send the hole file i've used: res.send(req.body);  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run *npm install body-parser*

And try this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

instead of this:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: Thanks, now the server is up and didn't return any error, however the .get calls are still not working. It's a very simple call:                       $.get( "gomerias.json", function( data ) {
          getCoordinates(data);
 });                                                                                                                        Do you have any idea why this is happening?. Cheers.

Comment: When i check the network console the .json file could be loaded, however it's empty...

Answer (score 1):

In the code that you have posted, the method app.get has return statement  as res.send ();  what is that you are sending here? Nothing actually. This is the reason for empty output when you make a get call on your app. Try sending at least a string like this

```
res.send ('welcome mate');
```

Comment: You're right, but how should i send the json file as the response?

Comment: Yes. Use Json.stringify method inside your res.send

Comment: right, but what the correct syntax, i mean how i specify the file?

Comment: Like this res.send ( JSON.stringify({ x: 5 }));

Answer (score 0):

```
res.send ( JSON.stringify({ x: 5 }));
```

Where {x:5} is your json object

Comment: Right, but how can specify a hole file, which is located in the root directory as "gomerias.json". I know that i can add json objects like that, but i need to point out a hole .json file. Thanks!

Comment: I've found out the uri for the json file was wrong, and to send the hole file i've used: res.send(req.body);  Thanks for your help!